# How to temporarily unbind the associations in cakephp 2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I only want to user `updateAll()` function but failed in unbinding associations. Does their is any possibility..? as official docs says

> By default, updateAll() will automatically join any belongsTo
> association for databases that support joins. To prevent this,
> temporarily unbind the associations.

Comment: Here is the [relevant part of the manual](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly).

Comment: Thanks @GregSchmidt, finally I'll find the solution and it works! :)